# How to control raspberry pi 4 GPIO pins by running android application in the rpi and in mobile?

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, android, relay

I am trying to build a project based on IoT. My goal is to trigger relays connected to GPIO pins in rpi4 by using an android application running in rpi4 itself which can be accessed with an official touchscreen. The same android app will run remotely in mobile. Overall, I will be able to trigger the relays using the touchscreen interface running android os in pi4 but also I can use the same application from my mobile to trigger them over the internet. And once the changes made in the rpi or in the mobile the trigger state will reflect dynamically on the other device as well, mobile or rpi.

I looked over the internet but there was no proper guidelines, I will be really grateful if anyone helps me with it or point me to specific direction on how to get started. Being a complete newbie its really difficult to pull this project off myself.

If there is any query please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support for android on RPI4 but here is guide to installing Android..

https://fossbytes.com/how-to-install-android-on-raspberry-pi-4/

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/androidthings for the GPIO code. Python and C on Raspberry Pi OS are much more common and better supported on the Pi than Android development.  There is a post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=307585 where the official screen does not work and a long thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=60008 on GPIO control from an Android phone but it uses Raspberry OS maybe the GUI can be a starting point?

Comment: so, will it be possible to make an RPI app using python and c to control GPIO pins and a mobile app to control their state over the internet?

Comment: Yes as long as your RPI has enough memory it works..  Mobile app over the internet will require setup of the network to allow your mobile requests to get to your RPI but that is all feasible with or without android.